# SVN Repo gives 404 not Found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, svn, webdav

I have installed svn, version 1.6.17 (r1128011) on to Ubuntu 12-04

I made my repo here:

```
$ sudo mkdir /home/2nd-disk/svn
```

Set up my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf

```
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /home/2nd-disk/svn
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Subversion Repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Created an account:

sudo htpasswd -cm /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd myusername

Created a test repo

```
$ cd /home/2nd-disk/svn

$ sudo svnadmin create test_repo
```

Ran a chown:

```
$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/2nd-disk/svn
```

Insured a2enmod & dav_svn are loaded and restarted apache2:

```
$ sudo a2enmod dav_svn && sudo service apache2 restart
Considering dependency dav for dav_svn:
Module dav already enabled
Module dav_svn already enabled
* Restarting web server  apache2
... waiting
```

I then try to browse to http://mydomain.com/svn/test_repo and I get a 404 not found.

The same happens with http://mydomain.com/svn/test_repo

Going to http://mydomain.com shows the default 'It Works!' apache page.

Do I need to change virtual hosts here? I followed this tutorial below to the T and so assumed not:

http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/svn-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-with-web-access/

Comment: `ls -R /home/2nd-disk/svn/test_repo` please and try in browser http://mydomain.com/svn/ after adding `SVNListParentPath on` in location container

Comment: Hmm. Still not found. Here is the contents of my repo http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hLtvfbvH. I added the 'SVNListParentPath on' clause. Restarted Apache2. Still I get a 404 when going to mydomain.com/svn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this problem sovled just now .
  prep. I set up my /etc/apache2/http.conf

```
LoadModule dav_module         /usr/lib/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   /usr/lib/apache2/mod_authz_svn.so
```

It works for a period without 404 while I then try to browse to http://mydomain.com/svn/test_repo .But after I reboot my Linux, I get a 404 not found.
Try to add the lines to /etc/apache2/conf.d.subversion.conf

```
LoadModule dav_module         /usr/lib/apache2/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module     /usr/lib/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   /usr/lib/apache2/mod_authz_svn.so
```

My SVN works well now! I wish these recommendations can help you.

Answer (score 0):

add the reference to your vhost instead of dav_svn.conf:

```
 <Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /var/local/svn
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Subversion repository"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
     Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
 </Location>
```

good tutorial is here: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Subversion

don't forget to restart apache to apply changes:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I don't quite follow. I should add the Location container to to a virtual host in sites-enabled/available?

Comment: yes, than everything should work well ;) let me know, if it worked out for you.