# Xcode 8 Unexpected HTTP status code: 404 (-1)

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode8, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to commit an Xcode project to a SVN server but I get this message: ***Unexpected HTTP status code: 404 (-1)***.

My credentials are correct and I'm using Xcode 8.

Any leads?

Thanks for your help.

[Xcode 8 message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAwSE.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to pin point what your actual problem is with the statement, but 404 is the standard response code for "Resource Not Found", I would suggest looking at the path you are trying to push to and seeing if it is configured on the server.  I have found another post on StackOverflow that speaks about conditions where you can receive a 404 while using SVN.

[SVN Repo gives 404 not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212363/svn-repo-gives-404-not-found)